# Approach to creating Dev, Tst, and Prod Deployment

Tags: zend-framework, deployment

My team spent the entire summer developing a simple micro-blogging application using the latest version of ZF1.

We're about to invest our money on a reliable VPN hosting server. Our goal is to create 3 environments - dev, test, and prod. Our idea is to create an Apache vhost configuration on the VPN server and setup test.domain.com that is only accessible from the server so that it is not accessible from the web by an ordinary user. Then our devs can tunnel into the server and access the test.domain.com. Is this doable? Has anyone tried this before? Is there a different approach that's better?

Answer (score 1):

Read up on Vhosts and you'll se that this is a quite common and simple thing to do. The following is an example based on my own Linux dev machine. Using this configuration the Apache will try to match the ServerName to the URL in the browser. If I put in test.domain.com it will match the test-site and there it will check which IP's are allowed to access the site. If I don't match that IP, Apache will return and "you are not allowed to view this directory error" (401 or 403 http code. Not sure which). If Apache doesn't find a match, it will use the first Vhost, and therefore your prod-site should go first.

A word of warning: Apache uses the URL in the browser to do the match, so if I edit my host-file I can trick apache. And subsequently If I successfully spoof my IP I can get access to your dev-site. Therefore, always use proper login/authentification and authorization procedures on both TEST and DEV sites to prevent any damage.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName domain.com, www.domain.com
           DocumentRoot /home/prod/document_root
        <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
        </Directory>   
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName dev.domain.com
           DocumentRoot /home/dev/document_root
        <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Order deny,allow
            Deny from all
            Allow from "localhost"
        </Directory>   
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName test.domain.com
           DocumentRoot /home/test/document_root
        <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Order deny,allow
            Deny from all
            Allow from "Some IPs"
        </Directory>   
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: After changing your host files above, don't forget to reload your apache service for changes to take effect ;)

Comment: I appreciate your thorough answer. We have a local vhost setup already. My question was whether its possible to create the same vhost setup on a VPS server. The answer is no because I asked customer service from hostgator.com and they replied that while setting a vhost is possible, it is not possible to install a VPN intra network on a VPS since VPS is virtual.

Comment: If the question was for a specific host-provider only that provider can answer and the questions doesn't really belong here on SO. It is however no problem to use Vhosts or/and VPN on a VPS with a properly configuered VLAN. We do that on a daily basis at the hosting company I work for.